# Texmaker vs. MikTex

Tags: latex

I finally got tired of trying to type mathematics in Word and am installing Tex on my desktop.  Any recommendation for which version to install?  I've used MikTex before (it's been a couple years now), but haven't tried any others.  A quick search returned a high number of recommendations for Texmaker.  I'm mainly looking for ease of use.

Comment: Texmaker is an editor, while MiKTeX is a TeX distribution. They're completely different things...

Comment: To elaborate on @Werner's comment. TeXmaker needs a LaTeX engine (so to say) in the background to compile latex files. MikTeX comes with a basic TeX editor (TeXworks) which is what you probably saw/used when you say used MikTeX. In general, TeXmaker has sufficient build options for anyone new to use it out of the box. If you like minimalistic interface, where you can see the output side-by-side, TeXWorks (default in MikTeX) should suffice, else TeXmaker is a good choice!

Comment: @Werner Do you want to add some kind of answer?